# Почему range создает весь возможный диапазон?

Tags: php

```
$count = 5;
$start = (int)(date('Ymd') . "0");  
$range = range($start, $count);

//Ожидается [201809240,201809241,201809242,201809243,201809244]
var_dump($range);
```

Но вместо этого вылетаю по памяти

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
>   8589934600 bytes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка в параметрах функции `range`

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.range.php

```
$range = range($start, $start + $count);
```